# How to fixe repeated callbacks in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have a problem with my jQuery code, that happens when I scroll to bottom to load more content.

My code:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= ($(document).height() - $(window).height())*0.9)
{
MyFonction();
}
});
```

When I scroll past the 90% mark of the page, I get repeated callbacks from **MyFonction** -- it is called multiple times.

Is there is a solution to make only one callback per scrolling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the debounce and throttle functions - two similar (but different!) techniques to control how many times we allow a function to be executed.

The Debounce technique allow us to "group" multiple sequential calls in a single one.

The Throttle technique only allows our function to execute once every X milliseconds.

Here are some very good articles and examples:

[How to change text element based on input text field in HTML using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38043171/how-to-change-text-element-based-on-input-text-field-in-html-using-javascript/38043208#38043208)

https://remysharp.com/2010/07/21/throttling-function-calls

https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/

https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

---

Another idea, that might be more suitable to this inquiry, is to ***also*** use a parent-scope variable to say whether you've scrolled past the 90% marker or not. Even using a throttler/debouncer, you will still get additional calls if the user stops and then starts again.

As a general rule, we usually use a debouncer whenever querying the `.scroll()` because there are so many events generated - but at 90%, you want to do something and not receive any further notifications until the next marker. So, use a variable for each marker and only check the scroll for that marker when that marker's variable is turned on.

Comment: can you please give me an example

Comment: Just use an ordinary variable - global vars if you must - that indicate if you are past 70% (turn on the check_90pct_var) and if it passes 90% then load in the new data and turn it off again, and have another one for the next point, etc. Old skool but it works. Dont forget about window.varname vars if you need them.